# Finding length of y-intecept made by circle.

Tags: geometry

The equation of the  circle is given as x^2+y^2+4x-7y+12=0, and this circle cuts an intercept on y-axis which is equal to what ?
options are (a)1 (b)2 (c)3 (d)0
AND CORRECT ANSWER IS GIVEN AS ''1''

Comment: Hint: the equation of the $Y$ axis is $x=0$.

Comment: plz provide detail solution

Comment: Please show that you’ve made some effort of your own to solve this. What part of the problem is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 1):

Setting $y=0$ we get for $x$: $x^2+4x+12=0$ and in the other Case
$x=0$: $y^2-7y+12=0$

Comment: how to get answer as 1

Answer (score 1):

$Y$  -axis : $x = 0.$

To find the $y -$intercepts set $x=0$ in the equation.

$y^2 - 7y +12= 0$, or

$(y-4)(y-3)=0.$

$y_1 =4$; $y_2=3.$

Points of intersection of circle with $y-$axis:

$(0,4)$ and $(0,3).$

The intercept is?

Comment: thanks for help

Comment: psi. Most welcome,